# AngularJS & WebAPI - Only returning one valid JSON Object

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api method that returns a list of entity framework Entities. The problem is that when I use PostMan, the api method is only returning ONE json object, even though I can see that the list in my web api method has multiple objects.

```
   public IEnumerable<EQUIPMENT> GetEquipmentWithIncidentID(int id)
    {
       var data = db.EQUIPMENTs.Where(d => d.INCIDENT.Id == id);
        return data.ToList();//has 2 objects, both with valid EQUIPMENT data
    }
```

Here is the JSON. I know it is long, but I see one issue.

```
[
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.EQUIPMENT_D790835B03D8AFA64882E425140B5DF282172396D2935CAF5839D425D4A34624, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
    "C_LINK_SELECTION": null,
    "C_LINK_SPECIAL": {
        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[DomainModelModule.C_LINK_SPECIAL, DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
        "$values": []
    },
    "DESIGNATOR": {
        "$id": "2",
        "$type": "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.DESIGNATOR_95426D806E5286A1F68EBAA09C9ECDE07E22D2B3D1F157C8121CD09A1FDE92C0, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
        "C_LINK": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[DomainModelModule.C_LINK_SELECTION, DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
            "$values": []
        },
        "C_LINK_SPECIAL": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[DomainModelModule.C_LINK_SPECIAL, DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
            "$values": []
        },
        "DIAL_DESIGNATOR": null,
        "EQUIPMENT": {
            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[DomainModelModule.EQUIPMENT, DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
            "$values": [
                {
                    "$ref": "1"
                },
                {
                    "$id": "3",
                    "$type": "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.EQUIPMENT_D790835B03D8AFA64882E425140B5DF282172396D2935CAF5839D425D4A34624, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
                    "C_LINK_SELECTION": null,
                    "C_LINK_SPECIAL": {
                        "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[DomainModelModule.C_LINK_SPECIAL, DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
                        "$values": []
                    },
                    "DESIGNATOR": {
                        "$ref": "2"
                    },
                    "INCIDENT": {
                        "$id": "4",
                        "$type": "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.INCIDENT_48C57B72A7ABE0D4324C23DD566C1D077603126FA76A0CF847BDEE2DAAAC5CDA, EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
                        "EQUIPMENTs": {
                            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[DomainModelModule.EQUIPMENT, DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
                            "$values": [
                                {
                                    "$ref": "3"
                                },
                                {
                                    "$ref": "1"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "FREQUENCies": {
                            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[DomainModelModule.FREQUENCY, DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
                            "$values": []
                        },
                        "LOGs": {
                            "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1[[DomainModelModule.LOG, DomainModelModule, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089",
                            "$values": []
                        },
                        "ZONE": null,
                        "Id": 1,
                        "Name": "TEST",
                        "IncidentProjectOrderNumber": "sdgsdg",
                        "FinancialCode": "sdgsdg",
                        "Latitude": "1254",
                        "Longitude": "124",
                        "IncidentReleaseDate": "2015-04-24T16:20:00",
                        "IsActive": false,
                        "IsCache": false
                    },
                    "Id": 2, //THIS IS THE START OF THE INFO THAT SHOULD APPEAR IN A SECOND EQUIPMENT ENTITY!!!
                    "SNumber": "hhhjj",
                    "BoxNumber": null,
                    "DateReleased": "2015-04-17T16:20:00",
                    "NFES": "sdeg",
                    "IssuedDate": null,
                    "ItemDescription": "sdeg",
                    "ModulationType": "FM",
                    "Bandwidth": "25 kHz",
                    "IsSpecial": false,
                    "RepeaterUsed": null,
                    "Technician": null,
                    "ADM": null
                }
            ]
        },
        "Id": 1,
        "DesignatorName": "C2",
        "TXFreq": "163.3375",
        "RXFreq": "167.9500",
        "IsSpecial": false,
        "IsCommand": false
    },
    "INCIDENT": {
        "$ref": "4"
    },
    "Id": 1,//And these are the basic properties of the first equipment entity
    "SNumber": "fff",
    "BoxNumber": null,
    "DateReleased": "2015-04-25T16:20:00",
    "NFES": "sadfsadg",
    "IssuedDate": null,
    "ItemDescription": "sadfsadg",
    "ModulationType": "AM",
    "Bandwidth": "None",
    "IsSpecial": false,
    "RepeaterUsed": null,
    "Technician": null,
    "ADM": null
},
{
    "$ref": "3"
}
```

]

The Top level entity object(EQUIPMENT), has the property "SNumber", and it looks like for some unknown reason when it returns the json, the other equipment object is getting partially nested within the first object, but I have no idea why.

And I have no idea what the "$ref:3" is.

Any ideas? I don't know what to try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding

```
    Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

To my DbContext().